# Validation is passing when it should fail - Michael Hartl's RoR, 6.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am trying to add validation to my User model, but instead of failing, the data keeps passing.  For name, I have no entry.  See below:

```
1.9.3p286 :012 > user = User.new(name: "", email: "fail@fail.com")
  => #<User id: nil, name: "", email: "fail@fail.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

1.9.3p286 :013 > user.save
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES    (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 23 Dec 2012 18:52:00 UTC +00:00], ["email",   "fail@fail.com"], ["name", ""], ["updated_at", Sun, 23 Dec 2012 18:52:00 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true
```

Here is what I have in `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible(:name, :email)

  validates(:name, presence: true)
end
```

This is supposed to fail.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I think u didn't reload a console after adding a validation